# Keeping the processes running even after exiting SSH to a windows machine

Tags: windows, tomcat, ssh, terminal

I am connecting to a remote machine through SSH client. Both SSH server and client are on windows OS.

I usually run tomcat 7 from such ssh session. But, as soon as I end the session, tomcat server shuts down as well. I run tomcat7.exe directly from its installation folder.

I have used &! at the end of the command to ensure that the process doesn't get attached to the terminal. But, couldn't achieve the desired result. 
Kindly suggest how to detach such processes from the ssh client.

Answer (score 0):

`tomcat7.exe start` and `tomcat7.exe stop` 
these two commands ensure that tomcat starts as a service. Worked like a charm for me.